# How can we localize a wallet pass's strip.png properly?

Tags: ios, localization, wallet, passkit

I am trying to localize a pass and save it in the iOS wallet.

The problem is that while the text on the back of the pass properly localizes, the strip.png image does not.

The strip.png image will be the image that was originally exported from my app.

So if my app was currently using the Spanish language, the Spanish strip.png would be exported.  If my language was set to English the English strip.png would be exported.

However, once it lives in the wallet app the strip.png no longer changes.  If the strip.png was in English and I switch the language to Spanish, the strip.png would still persist while the text on the back of the pass would change to Spanish as expected.

My .pkpass object contains two folders: en.lproj and es.lproj.

They both have their own localized version of strip.png and pass.strings file.

What am I doing wrong?
If localizing a strip.png is not supported then what are some other alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

You have come across a "feature" of Wallet, designed to save space on a user's device.  The rationale behind this feature is that users rarely change their base locale.

Once a .pkpass bundle has been installed on a device, all of the unnecessary image assets are dropped.

If, as it sounds, your pass is installed with the correct locale image, then your bundle is correct.  Unfortunately this means that to demo the locale functionality, you will need to delete and then reinstall the pass with a new language setting.

Comment: So pushing an update to the device will not change the locale since the new pass have all the files and the device has new locale settings?